# Try running MyCrypto with my local parity nodes?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet, poa, mycrypto

i want connect my local parity nodes with Mycrypto i flowed this tutorial to built my two nodes https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial.html
than i try to flow this tutorial to connect it to Mycrypto https://support.mycrypto.com/networks/run-your-own-node-with-mycrypto.html

im still straggling with connect my nodes to Mycrypto i need some help plz 
both my nodes work fine in terminals and they connected together and have users addresses and i can send eth from one to another fine by terminals.

so what is chain ID i tryed to add Enode URL and its not work i dont know how to connect that

thank you

[image]

Comment: what is MyCrypto in this sense, please provide more detail information in your question.

Comment: this is https://mycrypto.com/account

Comment: @HaĐANG MyCrypto is a wallet similar to MyEtherWallet, and the question is how to connect that wallet to a local parity private network.

Comment: @Ismael i still face problem to connect that what is the (chain ID)

Comment: If you can run a JSON-RPC command against your node, have you tried to call https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#net_version ?

Answer (score 1):

Before you connect to MyCrypto application you have to alter your node configuration to enable cors:

```
[rpc]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
cors = ["all"]
```

In bottom left select "Change Network" and then "Add custom node". In the pop up from "Network" select "Custom" at the bottom.

A new row appear that allow setting some parameters. The important is "Chain Id" use the "networkID" in your chain specification, convert to decimal "0x2323" -> "8995".

For URL use from your node.toml the port from RPC section, for example "http://localhost:8540".

---

MyCrypto allows to configure a custom node. In top center there's a drop down "Ethereum (AUTO)". The last option is "+ Add custom node".

A popup appears where you can input an URL to your node, in "Network" you can select the network type, ie mainnet, ropsten, POA or custom to select a arbitrary network id.

If you connect from https://MyCrypto.com it will require your node to use a secure https URL, but you can download the desktop app to connect to a local node, ie "http://localhost:8545".

Comment: Hi i cant run the node is not work for me im using desktop app i have two node and its run fine in the terminal

Comment: @Link I've updated my answer with instructions how to connect to the MyCrypto application